# WCF Service creates wcf Client proxy, starts transaction, calls proxy method but fails on Message Security

Tags: wcf, asp.net-membership

I am calling a WCF service from a WCF proxy(client) withing another WCF service as follows:

Client     ->     Service1  ->   Proxy.Method  ->  Service2

I use ASPNet Compatability everywhre with ASP.Net Membership configured and working everywhere. If I call the Service2 from the proxy using a TransactionSope I always get a message security error on Service2 which is unable to verify the message.

Looking at a WCF service trace (below) it looks like the problem seems to be the SqlProvider in Service2. I can only think that somehow a transaction might be deadlocked but calls to other services BEFORE the transaction have all completed successfully and they DON'T use transactions at all.

If I don't wrap the service call in a TransactionScope everything works fine! Anyone got any idea please?

Brian

131075
3
0
2





BRIANFURLONG-HP





http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IE/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx
Throwing an exception.
/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Nad.CheckoutServices.Host-20-129243786426619315

System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message security verification failed.

at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ServerSecurityChannel`1.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationState)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.ProcessReceivedRequest(RequestContext requestContext, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveRequestAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult.ProcessInnerItem(RequestContext innerItem, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.OnInnerReceiveDone()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.StartInnerReceive()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.Start()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityReplyChannel.BeginTryReceiveRequest(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReplyChannelBinder.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.BeginTryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.BeginTryReceive()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EnsurePump()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OpenAndEnsurePump(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.OnSecurityContextCallback(Object o)
at System.Security.SecurityContext.Run(SecurityContext securityContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
**<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Message security verification failed. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32&amp; status, String&amp; password, Int32&amp; passwordFormat, String&amp; passwordSalt, Int32&amp; failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32&amp; failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean&amp; isApproved, DateTime&amp; lastLoginDate, DateTime&amp; lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String&amp; salt, Int32&amp; passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator.MembershipProviderValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(String userName, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken token)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver, IList`1 allowedTokenAuthenticators, SecurityTokenAuthenticator& usedTokenAuthenticator)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 position, Byte[] decryptedBuffer, SecurityToken encryptionToken, String idInEncryptedForm, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.StrictModeSecurityHeaderElementInferenceEngine.ExecuteProcessingPasses(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved)
at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator.MembershipProviderValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(String userName, String password)
at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken token)
at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver, IList`1 allowedTokenAuthenticators, SecurityTokenAuthenticator&amp; usedTokenAuthenticator)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 position, Byte[] decryptedBuffer, SecurityToken encryptionToken, String idInEncryptedForm, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.StrictModeSecurityHeaderElementInferenceEngine.ExecuteProcessingPasses(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&amp; message, TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32&amp; status, String&amp; password, Int32&amp; passwordFormat, String&amp; passwordSalt, Int32&amp; failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32&amp; failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean&amp; isApproved, DateTime&amp; lastLoginDate, DateTime&amp; lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String&amp; salt, Int32&amp; passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNamePasswordValidator.MembershipProviderValidator.Validate(String userName, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateUserNamePasswordCore(String userName, String password)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.UserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateTokenCore(SecurityToken token)
   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenAuthenticator.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver, IList`1 allowedTokenAuthenticators, SecurityTokenAuthenticator& usedTokenAuthenticator)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ReadToken(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Int32 position, Byte[] decryptedBuffer, SecurityToken encryptionToken, String idInEncryptedForm, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteFullPass(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.StrictModeSecurityHeaderElementInferenceEngine.ExecuteProcessingPasses(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)

Comment: Are both services using the same membership DB? Does your service needs to include the membership DB in the Tx?

Comment: Yes, they both use the same single instance DB with ASPNet Membership installed while the transaction is using a second single instance db for the application. The application DB needs to be in the TRansaction, The membership DB does not need to be in the transaction. Indeed it is only being accessed for authentication purposes by WCF.

Comment: As I understand your description you are starting transaction in Service1 and you expect transaction to flow to Service2? Did you try to start transactio on Service2?

Comment: Yes, I am wrapping code in "using TransactionScope" in Service2 which should pick up the incoming ambient transaction. The issue seems to be that SQLServer is locking on the Membership call while the incoming transaction is open therefore preventing Service2 from even entering the method call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I realised the transaction was blocking the access to membership which was caused by accessing the Service2. Tnis was an issue with the way in which Membership handles transactions. It specifically forces "New Transaction" when it should simply enlist in the ambient transaction if it exists

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like you are using calling a service on http but it wants to use https.